# Show Ribbon in modal dialogs

Tags: 2010, ribbon, css, modal-dialog, dialog-framework

In the current project, they applied some branding, and for some reason the ribbon is hidden in modal dialogs like when creating a discussion board, task or any list item.

I cant find how they hide it, how can I enable it again?

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="x/custom.css" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

The custom.css file I paste it here

Comment: I have tested your css. The ribbon doesn't disappear in modal dialogs. It must be something else, or another css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and blogged about it here:
http://levalencia.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/how-to-hideshow-the-ribbon-bar-in-sharepoint-2010-dialogs-via-the-masterpage/

I will paste the solution below:

Well, this is pretty easy, and it came from this question over here:

[Show Ribbon in modal dialogs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30587/show-ribbon-in-modal-dialogs)

I started searching on CSS, but after sometime I found this article:

http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-pop-up-dialogs/

And then I compared the v4.master with the custom master page in our  project.

The big difference was only one line:

```
<div class="ribbon-fixedwidth s4-notdlg"></div>
```

After commenting this line I can see the ribbon on dialogs, Now I have other problems to solve.